# What is the canonical way to link to pages?

Tags: links, customization

I can easily link to my archives page by creating a link: `<a href="http://server.com/wordpress/archives.php">Archives</a>`. As I was editing my WP template, I noticed that there are a number of functions that WP uses to link to other pages. For example `get_the_category_list` returns a list of links. If I want to make my template more general, it would be nice not to hardcode the URL of my archives page and to use a WP function instead.

In general, how should template designers create links to WP generated pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link [Wordpress Codex: Linking...](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories) provides detailed information on how to link different types of content. One nice feature that solves the above problem is to use a link of the form `/wordpress/archives.php`. This will transfer nicely (in most cases) to any particular server deployment.

Further, looking in `wp-includes/link-template.php` gives you more insight to what kinds of tools are already available for creating links. Particularly helpful is `home_url()` which allows you to try to be as server agnostic as possible.